# How to (quickly) download huge amounts of data in Firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, csv, google-cloud-firestore

I'm sending data to the Firestore at 33Hz. This means that over time, a lot of data is stored.

I need to be able to download this data. For that, I have made a Http Function in firebase, that receives the user uid, device's serial number, start date/time and end date/time. The function then tests if the user exists and also if he does have that serial number. Then it queries firestore and append data to a JSON object, that eventually is send as a response.

But, depending on how long the query has been made, the function will timeout. It does work for short periods.

How should I do to make the function faster? Am I using the wrong tool?

```
[...]
const nD1 = db.collection('grind-bit').doc(req.query.serial).collection('history').where('date', '>=', startdate).where('date', '<=', enddate).get().then(snapshot => {
  snapshot.forEach(doc => {
    elem = {};
    elem.date = doc.data().date;
    elem.rms0 = doc.data().rms0;
    elem.rms1 = doc.data().rms1;
    elem.rms2 = doc.data().rms2;
    data[key].push(elem);
  });
  if(data[key].length) {
    let csv = json2csv(data[key]);
    csv = JSON.stringify(csv);
    res.set("Content-Type", "text/csv");
    return promises.push(res.status(200).send(csv));
  } else {
    return promises.push(res.status(401).send('No data has been found in this interval.'));
  }
[...]
```

Comment: You might want to add some log statements to your code to see where the time is going. The default timeout for Cloud Functions is 60 seconds, so if you go through that period it should be findable with simple log statements.

Comment: I've done this already. The time is spend mostly during the forEach(). I also tried increasing the timeout, but this does not make things faster. Also, I've noticed that these queries are costly. I'm searching for an alternative.

Comment: Can you drill down on the "during the `forEach()`" part? What specific instruction in there takes the time? Because at first glance it all seems fairly straightforward. Also: how many items are you processing in that loop when it becomes a problem? Dozens? Thousands? Hundreds of thousands?

Comment: I was wrong. I queried about 10k documents (4 fields each). It did take 7.7 seconds until the end of the .get() and 0.084s during the forEach(). 
I want to be able to get at least 200k documents (or more). Thank you for your time btw.

Comment: OK. So reading of the documents doesn't take most of the time. But processing 200K documents will always take significant time, and 200K  * 0.084s = 16800 seconds, so far more than the 60-540 second maximum time that a Cloud Function can run. So unless you can find a way to significantly speed up the processing of each document (seems unlikely), you'll have to do what I answered and process the data in chunks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the timeout is caused by the fact that you're trying to read/return too much data in one go, you might want to consider limiting how much data you return. By adding a `limit()` clause to your query, you can limit how much data it returns at most.

```
const nD1 = db.collection('grind-bit').doc(req.query.serial).collection('history')
.where('date', '>=', startdate).where('date', '<=', enddate)
.limit(100)
.get().then(snapshot => {
  snapshot.forEach(doc => {
    ...
```

This of course means that you may have to call the HTTP function multiple times to ensure you process all data. The simplest approach for that is: if you get 100 results (or whatever limit your specify), try another time after processing them.

Also see:

- The Firebase documentation on [limiting query results](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data)

Comment: I have implemented that, and it worked.
While I was implementing I had the idea of dividing the query into a series of smaller queries asynchronously. Then the response would have to be sorted, but way faster. Thank you for your answer!